# SVM Multiclass Image classification with probability outputs

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to classify an Image using support vector machines (SVM) of OpenCV and I get this error (OpenCV Error: Bad argument (train data must be floating-point matrix) in cvCheck
TrainData, file ......\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp, line 857) during SVM training. 
So far I converted the data to rows of floating data type but still get an error. I would also like to predict and save the final classes of the image. Kindly advice me, my code is as below. 
Is there a multiclass SVM classification code example somewhere I can follow?
Thanks.

```
int main()
{
    //Read image;
    register int iii, jjj;  
    Mat image = imread("E:\\DATA\\Dummy\\Input\\ImageFeatures.jpg");
    const int rows = image.rows, cols = image.cols, bands = image.channels();
    Mat reshapedImage; 
    reshapedImage = image.reshape(bands, image.rows * image.cols);
    reshapedImage.convertTo(reshapedImage,CV_32FC1);

    // Set up labels
    Mat imagelabels = imread("E:\\DATA\\Dummy\\Input\\TrainingSet.bmp", CV_8UC1);
    Mat labels;
    labels = imagelabels.reshape(1, rows * cols);
    labels.convertTo(labels, CV_32FC1);

    // Set up SVM's parameters
    CvSVMParams params;
    params.svm_type    = CvSVM::C_SVC;
    params.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF; //RBF
    params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);
    params.C           = 10;
    params.gamma       = 0.9;

    // Train the SVM
    CvSVM SVM;
    SVM.train(reshapedImage, labels, Mat(), Mat(), params);

    //Vec3b green(0,255,0), blue (255,0,0), red(0,0,255), gray(230,230,230);
    float response = SVM.predict(reshapedImage);
    Mat solution;
    for (iii = 0; iii < image.rows; iii++)
        for (jjj = 0; jjj < image.cols; jjj++)
        {
            float response = SVM.predict(reshapedImage);
            solution.at<float>(iii,jjj)  = response;      
        }

    // Show the training data
    imwrite("result.bmp", solution);        // save the image
    solution.convertTo(solution,CV_8UC1);
    imshow("SVM Simple Example", solution); // show it to the user
    waitKey(0);

}
```

In my case I have a 1000 by 1000 pixel image and a corresponding fully labelled 1000 by 1000 pixel image with five classes (with labels from 0 to 4). How best do I deal with this scenario?

Comment: it's no use training an svm on a single image, also, your labels are an image, too ? labels must be a single col Mat with 1 number per traindata row.

Comment: Before going further, `SVM` is itself a typedef in the `cv` namespace, you should reconsider naming your svm object that.

Comment: In my case I have a 1000 by 1000 pixel image and a corresponding fully labelled 1000 by 1000 pixel image with five classes (with labels from 0 to 4). How best do I deal with this scenario?